# Why does this Python program loop indefinitely?

Tags: python

```
x = 25
epsilon = 0.01
step = 0.1
guess = 0.0

while guess <= x:
    if abs(guess**2 -x) >= epsilon:
        guess += step

if abs(guess**2 - x) >= epsilon:
    print('failed')
else:
    print('succeeded: ' + str(guess))
```

I am given this Python program which attempts to calculate the square root of a number `x`. For some reason, this program loops indefinitely and I'm not sure why.

There are only finitely many values of `guess`, because, after `guess>x` (i.e. when `guess>=25.1`,, the `while` loop then stops). The `while` command in the middle of the program is the only thing that loops, so what is happening?

Comment: Put some print statements in and find out

Comment: So what happens when `guess = 5.0`? Your `if` statement won't match but `guess <= x` still true.

Comment: You don't stop the loop if the guess is within epsilon.

Comment: Please have a look at
[Methods of computing square roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots)
to implement a square root computation algorithm.
A naive search is not performant at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only increment `guess` when the condition `abs(guess**2 -x) >= epsilon` is true. That condition is *false* when `guess = 5.0`. At that point `guess` never changes anymore but `guess <= x` is still true and you enter an infinite loop:

```
>>> x = 25
>>> epsilon = 0.01
>>> guess = 5.0
>>> abs(guess**2 - x)
0.0
>>> abs(guess**2 - x) >= epsilon
False
```

Starting at `guess = 0.0` and incrementing by `0.1` means that your loop executes 50 times before reaching that point, after which `guess` never changes again.

In reality, `guess` is not `5.0` exactly because adding an approximation of `0.1` (which can't be represented exactly using binary fractions), gives you a value a small amount lower:

```
>>> guess = 0.0
>>> for _ in range(50):
...     guess += 0.1
...
>>> guess
4.999999999999998
```

but that difference is still smaller than `epsilon`.

You probably want to *break* the `while` loop when you have reached within `epsilon` distance of the target:

```
while guess <= x:
    if abs(guess**2 -x) < epsilon:
        break
    guess += step
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you change the while condition to `<` instead of `<=`, it will still loop indefinitely, because of floating point inaccuracy.

Although you add steps of 0.1, the `guess` value will not become exactly 5, but 4.999999999999998, at which point the loop will continue to run without entering in the `if` block.

This is at least what I see happening [here](https://repl.it/Dz1g/6)

Comment: The stepsize is 0.1, not 0.01. 50 * 0.1 is still 5.0 exactly (`(50 * 0.1).is_integer()` is true).

Comment: Maybe it depends on the processor, because I see it happening [here](https://repl.it/Dz1g/6).

Comment: No, I can reproduce it when I step away from multiplication and use addition 50 times.

Comment: Indeed, I just came to the same conclusion :)